# .CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, opencv

I downloaded the project of gender detection from OpenCV but I'm facing a problem in function `highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE`. I already changed          the highgui to imgproc but now it shows `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` cannot be resolved or is not a field. Here is the code snippet from the gender detection OpenCV program:

```
for(int i=0; i<types; i++)
{
    standardImages[i] = new Mat(size, Imgproc.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 standardImages[i] = new Mat(size, Imgproc.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

by

```
 standardImages[i] = new Mat(size, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this change is necessary because of the transition from OpenCV 2.4 to 3.0 when [numerous changes](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html#gsc.tab=0) were introduced.